# My 2010 Honda Civic cranks but won't start

Tags: honda, battery, civic, cranks-wont-run

My 2010 Honda Civic quit starting today. For the past week I have heard it starting up slower than usual. What would usually be an instant startup took 2-3 seconds. Today when I attempted to start it up, I hear it turn over but it won't fully start. Other than the issue starting up, I haven't had any noticeable problems driving.

I suspect it may be a dead/dying battery. I can leave it in Start (II) and see lights on the dash, and the A/C powers on, but I noticed the radio says "Enter Code". Since the radio was working 2 days ago, I assume it ran out of power at some point. When I go to Ignition (III) I can hear it cranking but it gets noticeably weaker the longer I let it turn over. I stopped attempting to start it after a couple of tries.

Is it most likely a battery problem? Can I get a jump and take it to a shop?

Comment: I think the problem could be anything. The best solutions is to take your vehicle to the car mechanic shop.

Comment: What about the fuel pump? Could that be a possibility? Or fuel filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it most likely a battery problem?

Yes. Weak cranking is a tell-tale sign. The radio most likely needs a certain voltage to remain operational, so your observations point to a weak battery.

> Can I get a jump and take it to a shop?

Yes, sure.

Comment: Thanks! They changed the battery and it seems to be working just fine now.